# $_SESSION's are not being retrieved

Tags: php, session

I have sessions on 3 individual pages:

teacherlogin.php (page 1)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {   
      session_start(); 
$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $row['TeacherForename'];
$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $row['TeacherSurname'];

  }
```

create_session.php (page 2)

```
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $dataArray[$row['CourseId']]['CourseName'] = $row['CourseName']; 
            $dataArray[$row['CourseId']]['Modules'][$row['ModuleId']]['ModuleName'] = $row['ModuleName']; 

$_SESSION['idcourse'] = $row['CourseId'];
$_SESSION['namecourse'] = $row['CourseName'];

    }
```

QandATable.php (page 3)

```
session_start();
<p>{$_SESSION['courseid']}  {$_SESSION['namecourse']}</p>
<p>{$_SESSION['teacherforename']} {$_SESSION['teachersurname']}</p>
```

Now what happens is that page 3 is able to retrieve the $_SESSION's from page 1, but when I try and get page 3 to retrieve $_SESSIONS from page 2, it comes with an undefined index notice for both page 2 $_SESSIONS. Why is this?

I tried including session_start() for page 2 but it comes back with notice stating session has already started so ignoring session_start().

Comment: Do you have session_start() in page 2?

Comment: You should never call `session_start()` inside a loop.

Comment: You shouldn't create your sessions inside a loop (p.1) And you forgot to start your session in page 2.

Comment: I tried including session_start() on page 2 but it comes back with notice stating session_start() has already started so session_start() ignored.

Comment: Call session_start() at the very top of every page you hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting a new session for each result. Move the session_start() function to be before the while loop.

Comment: Thank you all of you for the help, you fixed the problem, this answer will be ticked when it allows me to in 5 minutes